# How can I browse Maildir directories?

Tags: maildir

I've backed up some email accounts (e.g. Gmail) using getmail. The mails are stored locally using the Maildir format. My question is, how can I browse these mails? Preferably I would not have to use dovecot just some kind of local client

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Kmail, Evolution, mutt and heilroom-mailx support Maildir. And of course dovecot. ;)

Comment: [and there are others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir#Mail_readers)

Answer (score 0):

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) has a good user maildir browser feature.

Comment: Ok, but I would prefer some kind of local client

Comment: @EliahKagan  I have deleted my comment, but this was flagged.  Unfortunately, there are no option that say, answer incomplete, or short answer, try to improve.:)

Comment: @Mitch What do you mean when you say that it was flagged? Do you mean it was in the review? You do know that (1) many items in the review shouldn't actually be deleted, and most items there aren't there because they were flagged by an actual person, but rather because they were detected automatically as ***possibly*** low quality, and (2) when you vote to delete in the low-quality review, you don't *have* to leave a comment, and you can also leave your own custom comment, the same way you'd comment if you just came upon the post normally. Right?